# Parameter display

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have four text parameters with dropdowns.  I need the textbox portion to display nothing.  All I have been able to do so far is get either a NULL or the  option (which means a value is mandatory).  The user needs to be able to select multiple values, one value or no value at all.

How do I get a blank textbox?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Juniormint

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a blank value to your list of available options and test for that in your query.

Assuming your available values list of options comes from a SQL query then just UNION an empty string to the end something like

```
SELECT Caption FROM myTable
UNION ''
ORDER BY Caption
```

You can set the default value to be an empty string.

In your main dataset you can do a test something like

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable
WHERE (myColumn = @myParameter OR @myParameter = '')
```